# Reading/Writing to outfile error (Probably Simple Fix)

Tags: c++, string, variables, int, ifstream

So I'm sure there is allot of "inefficient" code here, but I am just learning.

The problem I'm having here is when I display the previous high score (which is saved in "Score.txt" in the following format:

```
NAME
score right wrong
```

So it looks like this:

```
Bob
40 2 2
```

Saving the score works perfectly, however, ifstream is pulling the wrong information. Instead of displaying the previous high score information (Score = 40, Right = 2, Wrong = 2) it displays numbers like -80883004 or similar.

Anyone see what could be causing this from the code below?

```
void Score(int score, string name, int qRight, int qWrong)
{
    infile.open("Score.txt");

    string nameHS;
    int scoreHS, rightHS, wrongHS;
    char choice;

    getline(infile, nameHS);
    infile >> scoreHS;
    infile >> rightHS;
    infile >> wrongHS;

    system("CLS");

    cout << "You have completed Trivia!\n\n";
    cout << setw(30) << "Your Score  " << setw(30) << "High Score  " << '\n';
    cout << setw(30) << "--------------" << setw(30) << "--------------" << '\n';
    cout << setw(25) << "| Score: " << setw(3) << score << " |"
        << setw(25) << "| Score: " << setw(3) << scoreHS << " |" << '\n';
    cout << setw(25) << "| Right: " << setw(3) << qRight << " |"
        << setw(25) << "| Right: " << setw(3) << rightHS << " |" << '\n';
    cout << setw(25) << "| Wrong: " << setw(3) << qWrong << " |"
        << setw(25) << "| Wrong: " << setw(3) << wrongHS << " |" << '\n';
    cout << setw(30) << "--------------" << setw(30) << "--------------" << "\n\n";

    if (score > scoreHS)
    {
        cout << "Congratulations! You beat the high score!\n\n";
        cout << "Would you like to save your score?\n";
        cout << "(Y/N): ";
        cin >> choice;

        if (choice == 'y' || choice == 'Y')
            saveScore(score, name, qRight, qWrong);
        else if (choice == 'n' | choice == 'N')
            cout << "\nPlay again soon!\n\n";
        else
            cout << "Invalid option... game save incomplete! Good-Bye!\n\n";
    }
    outfile.close();
}

void saveScore(int score, string name, int qRight, int qWrong)
{
    system("CLS");

    cout << "Your HIGH SCORE has been saved!\n";
    cout << "Good luck next game ....\n\n";

    outfile.open("Score.txt", ofstream::out | ofstream::trunc);

    outfile << name << '\n';
    outfile << score << ' ' << qRight << ' ' << qWrong << '\n';

    outfile.close();
}
```

Comment: When IO goes wrong (or before it does...) it is good pratice to control the result of any opening or reading function. And why do you mix getline and stream extractors?

Comment: What would be a better option? Keep in mind I'm new to this...I am not entirely sure what a stream extractor is? Are you referring to getline and infile >> being together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think your input file is opening.  After opening infile, add the following check,

```
bool bIsOpen = infile.is_open();
```

Make sure bIsOpen is true.  If it is set to false, you probably need to place your input file in a different directory.  If you are using Visual Studio, check the working directory and place the file there.

Comment: Added the check to verify infile is opening and it is, so still uncertain of what the problem could be.

Comment: Your code works on my computer.  I'm using Visual Studio 2015.  What is your dev environment?  Maybe there is something wrong with your input file???

Comment: That's strange, I'm using VS 2015 as well. And I can't seem to find anything wrong with the input file. I've manually typed it in, and relied on my output to format it and replace with the data used.....Did you literally copy/paste my code and it worked fine?

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved! I forgot to close all the previous instances of the open files. Must have been causing an error somehow. Thanks to those who helped!

Comment: Give me some love and up vote my post. :)  I at least got you going in the right direction that it was something with your input file.  I'm glad to see you got things working.  Good luck!